# Eclipse RCP how to get composite parent

Tags: java, eclipse, parent, rcp, composite

I want to create tableviewer in RCP but I don't know how to get "Composite parent". I have this code :

```
@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent) {
    Books.generateBooks();
    Map<String, Books> allBooks = Books.returnAllBooks();
    List<String> booksList = new ArrayList<String>(allBooks.keySet());

    tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent);

    for(int i=0; i<booksList.size(); i++) {
        tableViewer.add(booksList.get(i));
    }

    tableViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) tableViewer.getSelection();
            if (selection.isEmpty()) return;
            BibliotekaSzczegolyPart.createComposite(selection.getFirstElement().toString());
        }
    });
    tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL));
}
```

It creates table view in my part, and add DoubleClickListener in table positions. Now I want to create function createComposite in another class which I want to activate after double click but then I don't have "Composite parent" because it is not @PostConstruct. How to get it?

Comment: What is this other class going to be? A dialog? A MPart? Something in your existing part?

Comment: It is a class connected to another part. I have two part - first is a list of books, second is a part with books details. I have double click on list of books part and this after click I want to create details of books in second part.

Comment: That's right I want to have reference to part. How can I get it?

Comment: The best way to do this is to use the event broker to send a event that the other part can listen for. That way you don't need a reference to the other part.

Comment: Could You tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the event broker to send a event that the other part can listen for. That way you don't need a reference to the other part.

To send an event:

```
@Inject
IEventBroker eventBroker;

String value = .... value you want to send (doesn't have to be a string)

eventBroker.post("/my/topic", value);
```

To listen for the event include a method like this in the class that wants to listen (assumes the class is created by injection):

```
@Inject
@Optional
public void event(@UIEventTopic("/my/topic") final String value)
{
  if (value != null) {
    // TODO Handle value
  }
}
```

You may get a call to  the method with a `value` set to `null` while the part is being initialized so check for that.

The method name can be anything you like.

`@UIEventTopic` forces the event to arrive on the UI thread. Use `@EventTopic` if you don't care about the thread.

The topic name can be whatever you choose but it must contain `/` separators as shown.

More detail in [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html) tutorial.

Comment: I am afraid that I need reference to second part because I want to create tableViewer in this second part - to do this I need to have "Composite parent".

Comment: Your second part should have been given the parent when it was created - remember it for the event. Or are you saying you need to create the part now - use the `EPartService` to show it.

Comment: Which event should I use?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking - what event for what?

Comment: Honestly I am new in RCP. Now I have two part - one with books list (my code is in a question) and second with book details. After double click on book title from first part I want to show book details in second part. First part is connected with BibliotekaAllPart.java and second BibliotekaDetailPart.java. How can I do that?

Comment: This is getting far too broad. I have shown you how to communicate between parts which are already open. If you want to open a new part in response to the double click that is a different question.